# How can I adapt my chart size according to my datas automatically in QT?

Tags: qt, charts, qchartview

I have a scrolling dynamic chart. When the new data come, I cannot see because the chart size. Can I automatize it? Does qt charts have a property like that? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo6re.png)

```
void MainWindow::initChartView()
{
    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    qDebug()<< series;
    QPen green(Qt::red);
    green.setWidth(2);
    series->setPen(green);
    chart->legend()->hide();
    chart->setTitle("deneme");
    chart->setAnimationOptions(QChart::AllAnimations);


    QValueAxis *axisX=new QValueAxis;
    axisX->setTickCount(5);
    axisX->setRange(0, 2);
    chart->addAxis(axisX, Qt::AlignBottom);
    series->attachAxis(axisX);


    QValueAxis *axisY = new QValueAxis;
    axisY->setTickCount(5);
    axisY->setRange(0,2);
    chart->addAxis(axisY, Qt::AlignLeft);
    series->attachAxis(axisY);

    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    this->setCentralWidget(chartView);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo6re.png)

Comment: Your linked image does not show a chart.

Comment: I've edit it. Sorry for it

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to resize the chart. Maybe instead of resizing, you actually want it to scroll when new data comes in? Try searching SO for similar questions and see what you find.

Comment: I've try to scroll chart, but it scroll the screen, not the chart